# hammer.js Object doesn't support property or method 'create'

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I using hammer.js on my web site, it's working great on chrome , but not working on IE11.

I got this error :

> Unhandled exception at line 25, column 9 in
>   http://localhost:59764/js/hammer.js
>
> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property
>   or method 'create'

It's in this function in the hammer.js file.

```
function h(a, b, c) {
    var d, e = b.prototype;
    d = a.prototype = Object.create(e),
    d.constructor = a,
    d._super = e,
    c && f(d, c)
}
```

Is there a way to solve that ?

Comment: Check that you aren't in compatibility mode. Click the cog in top right corner -> compatibility view settings -> either remove the website from the list, or uncheck 'display intranet sites in Compatibility View'.

Comment: I think it is not compatible with  IE11 yet, Please see [link]https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki/Compatibility . Use compatibility mode as mentioned by @ManishKr.Shukla

Comment: I tried to remove the check box , but it didn't resolved the problem.
on wiki they don't say anything about IE11.

Comment: This is all outdated Wiki. You should look here: http://hammerjs.github.io/browser-support/ are you on the latest hammer.js version?

Comment: @AnandThakur: No, Manish Kr. Shukla did recommend *not* to use quirks ("compatibilty") mode